# LuaJIT and LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, lua

Is it possible to change the Lua engine in LuaTeX to LuaJIT?

Will it be as simple as replacing the Lua5.1 source code in the LuaTeX tarball with the LuaJIT source, or does it require (drastic) changes to the build system, or is it entirely not possible?

Comment: What would the advantage be over the current situation?

Comment: It is "claimed" to be faster. But I doubt if that performance boost will benefit LuaTeX much. On my MacBook pro the bottleneck of performance is loading fonts. But I believe that is actually related to the hard disk and memory since the loading time is almost proportional to the size of the fonts cache file. For example ArnoPro-Regular has an unbelievable 53MB cache file and cost in multi-GB memory after loading the standard two weights two shapes. This leads it to be extremely slow to load, while LMRoman will take little time to be noticed.

Comment: @YanZhou: That would depend on whether the function is implemented in Lua.  In the case of loading otf fonts, AFAIK, the metric-extracting part done by fontforge libraries.  I'm not sure about the loading-of-the-cached-metrics part, though.  If that part is indeed implemented in Lua, then theoretically we should see both a speed increase and a memory usage decrease if LuaJIT is embedded instead of Lua5.1.

Comment: I have TeX runs that last several minutes (up to an hour) and a few percent gain would be nice.

Comment: @JonathanYip, actually I still doubt that. What I see is that when loading metrics, which I believe is implemented in lua as the cache file is actually just lua files, luatex is almost idle, while the hard disk is at high speed. LuaJit may improve the memory usage. But for speed, on a traditional hard drive, i.e., non-ssd, IO is not going to be improved much for modest or large files. Writing files can be improved by better caching, but reading files is more complicated. In addition, IO involves system calls. That's why IO operations depends more the OS than compiler/interpreter.

Comment: @YanZhou: That may be true for LuaLaTeX; ConTeXt MkIV makes heavy use of Lua so it might gain quite some speed.

Comment: @YanZhou: Of course there's bound to be portions of the Lua(La)TeX typeset-compilation procedure that are IO-bound.  Without actual profiling it would be meaningless to assert whether if a JIT compiler would help in which procedure of the code.  Nonetheless the main question here is whether the incorporation of LuaJIT, which is designed to be a drop-in replacement for the Lua interpreter, is trivial to implement by the user by some simple patching of the LuaTeX source.  Whether if this should be goal to be pursued upstream is another question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I did an attempt a while ago with LuaJIT 1, and it did not seem to be that hard. A few small build tweaks would be needed, but nothing major.

The main reason why there is no LuaJIT in LuaTeX currently is that we have a few patches to Lua now that are not in LuaJIT (and are hard to add) like an extended coroutine subsystem. In lua5.2, our patches to the Lua core will become obsolete, so once we switch to that Lua version, LuaJIT becomes interesting again and I will certainly try to have LuaJIT support by default on the supported platforms. 
That should be before LuaTeX 1.0, but not in next few months.

But, don't expect much of it. Even in ConTeXt, most Lua processing is iterating over C data structures using our embedded Lua support libraries. JITting the little bit of Lua code that wraps that together will not help a lot, a few percent at best is my current guess (which is also why incorporating LuaJIT is low priority)

Answer (score 12):

Since 2012-12-25 LuaJitTeX is available. It is LuaTeX with LuaJit based on Lua
5.1.

Two modes are available by default:

- jit turned off, the default mode (only use the faster virtual machine)
- jit turned on (in most cases not faster, even slower)

In ConTeXt standalone LuaJitTeX is included by default, which means using MkIV
with LuaJitTeX is as easy as providing the `--jit` argument:

```
context --jit   somefile.tex  # or
context --jiton somefile.tex
```

For plainTeX simply use `luajittex` as compiler:

```
luajittex         --fmt=luajittex-plain.fmt somefile.tex  # or
luajittex --jiton --fmt=luajittex-plain.fmt somefile.tex
```

Building the format for plainJitTeX is no different than building the format
for LuaTeX.

Just to provide an impression of the speed difference I did a quick
non-scientific test on a simple document. Here are the results for a ConTeXt
document with the three possible options:

```
Engine                      Compile time
------                      ------------
LuaTeX                      3.6s
LuaJitTeX (jit turned off)  2.9s
LuaJitTeX (jit turned on)   3.0s
```

*Edit:* There seems to be some confusion about how to obtain LuajitTeX. The project is hosted on [foundry.supelec.fr - LuajitTeX](https://foundry.supelec.fr/projects/luajittex/). Recently they restructured their servers and relocated their content. Unfortunately the URLs changed and the old ones are not valid any longer. The sources can be obtained with SVN using

```
svn checkout --username anonsvn https://foundry.supelec.fr/svn/luajittex/trunk
```

The binaries can be found [on the ConTeXt garden.](http://svn.contextgarden.net/suite-bin/tex/)

Comment: Where is LuaJitTex available? The link on the luatex homepage points to http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/luajittex but this seems not to work anymore (404).

Comment: Have you tried this timing with immensely large documents?

Comment: No and it might not be of practical use to me. For large documents the complexity tends to increase paired with extensively using external programs during the run, but my documents rarely comprise more than a few hundred pages. It might not be too hard to create an example where either LuaTeX or Jit is faster but that result might be of limited value in practice.

Comment: Be aware that luajit has ffi: `http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html` which can increase performance drastically if used properly. The links are still down though after several months. So is there no luaJITLatex?

Comment: @Archival The URL changed to [LuajitTeX project page](https://foundry.supelec.fr/projects/luajittex/). I don't use LaTeX, but isn't it as simple as building the format and call `luajittex --fmt=luajitlatex.fmt file.tex`? If the format builds with luatex it should build with luajittex as well.

Comment: @Marco I have no idea but it would be nice to know. I have a project that runs off of lualatex and is very slow to run. Could you explain how I might get it to compile using luajittex?

Comment: Also, there seems to be nothing on that link you posted(no way to download or anything)?

Comment: LuajitTeX seems to be part of TeX Live nowadays.