# When to use LuaJitTeX in favour of LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex

Since a few weeks [LuaJitTeX is
available ¹](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.luatex/2911), which is
LuaTeX with Lua replaced by LuaJIT. Binaries are available for various
platforms. It is already included in the ConTeXt standalone distribution.

I wonder which sort of documents benefit from using LuaJitTeX? If non-standard fonts
are used XeTeX is a good choice, if MetaPost is involved LuaTeX is a
good choice, just to give an example.

- What's exactly the use case for LuaJitTeX?
- Does it ever make sense to turn Jit on (in contrast to just using the virtual machine of LuaJitTeX)? The ConTeXt help states: `--jiton
  jit turned on (in most cases not faster, even slower)` and [running a small
  test](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97827/5245) suggests that it really appears to be
  slower. I don't know if that is always the case and I wonder if there are any
  counter examples.

¹ <sub>The source code can be obtained with: `svn co http://foundry.supelec.fr/svn/luajittex/trunk`. The binaries can be found on http://svn.contextgarden.net/suite-bin/tex/.</sub>

Answer (score 13):

I use `luajittex` whenever possible with [our database publishing system](http://speedata.github.io/publisher/). It gives me a huge performance gain (~30%) compared to the regular `luatex` binary.

99% of our code is Lua, so the gain is expected and probably cannot be achieved with normal LaTeX packages (I'd expect a 5% gain at most).

Currently I don't turn the JIT on. Perhaps in the future I will do that. First I need more testing if the binaries on all the required platforms (mac/linux/win 32bit and 64 bit) are "bug free" (whatever that means).